# Windows 8.1 App installation failed

Tags: c#, xaml, powershell, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I've created a **Windows 8.1 Store App** and I'm try to install the app on another pc.
I run powershell file from the app package. It asked for a developer account and I entered invalid credentials and hence the installation failed.
The second time I run the powershell file I get the following error[image]
It does not prompt me re-enter the credentials rather shows the above screen.
How do I get rid of this ?

Comment: Did you try to delete the license?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx#getting_a_developer_license_at_a_command_prompt

Comment: @dani : yes I did delete the license, rebooted the machine and tried to run the powershell file. But, again the same error.

Comment: Maybe you should check the credential manager in the control panel.